# Disable Zip Code Magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento

Alright, my website is almost done.
I`ve installed IWD One page checkout and i made Zip Code Entry "Hidden"
But i want this field out from "My account" as well.
Any hint please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find code for Zip Code fields in frontend `My Account` section in these files:

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/customer/form/register.phtml
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/customer/form/address.phtml
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/customer/address/edit.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code')

this is the code line that you will find in .phtml files.
Use Path Hint to get .phtml path.

So delete that line from customer/form/register.phtml and other .phtml files.